# Sort filenames in directory in ascending order with two levels

Tags: python, sorting

I have a directory with .jpg files (frames from different video files). Filenames look like 'frame_{}_{}'.format(number_of_video, frame_number).
For example: 'frame_1_1234.jpg'

How I can sort files in ascending order with two-level sorting? Firstly by number_of_video and secondly by frame_number.

Now I have this:

```
['frame_0_0.jpg','frame_0_1.jpg','frame_0_10.jpg','frame_0_100.jpg','frame_0_1000.jpg','frame_0_1001.jpg','frame_0_1002.jpg','frame_0_1003.jpg','frame_0_1004.jpg','frame_0_1005.jpg','frame_0_1006.jpg','frame_0_1007.jpg',...]
```

I want to have this:

```
['frame_0_0.jpg', 'frame_0_1.jpg', 'frame_0_2.jpg',..., 'frame_1_0.jpg', 'frame_1_1.jpg', 'frame_1_2.jpg',...]
```

Clearly .sorted() blindly the most significant number first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `key` parameter of [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
import re


def key(value):
    """Extract numbers from string and return a tuple of the numeric values"""
    return tuple(map(int, re.findall('\d+', value)))


values = ['frame_0_0.jpg', 'frame_0_1.jpg', 'frame_0_10.jpg', 'frame_0_100.jpg',
          'frame_0_1000.jpg', 'frame_0_1001.jpg', 'frame_0_1002.jpg', 'frame_0_1003.jpg',
          'frame_0_1004.jpg', 'frame_0_1005.jpg', 'frame_0_1006.jpg', 'frame_0_1007.jpg']

result = sorted(values, key=key)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['frame_0_0.jpg', 'frame_0_1.jpg', 'frame_0_10.jpg', 'frame_0_100.jpg', 'frame_0_1000.jpg', 'frame_0_1001.jpg', 'frame_0_1002.jpg', 'frame_0_1003.jpg', 'frame_0_1004.jpg', 'frame_0_1005.jpg', 'frame_0_1006.jpg', 'frame_0_1007.jpg']
```

Notice that the key uses a regular expression for finding the numbers inside the string, you can find more about them, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

Comment: @DmitryF If my answer help you, please consider marking it as accepted. It signals others that your problem was solved.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't have enough reputation for marking it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a list of tuples `(number_of_video, frame_number)`, sort the list, and after that create the filenames.

```
tuples = [(0,0), (0,1), (0,10), (0,100), (0,1000), ...]
filenames = [f"frame_{t[0]}_{t[1]}.jpg" for t in sorted(tuples)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this too.

set1 = ['frame_0_0.jpg','frame_0_1.jpg','frame_2_10.jpg','frame_1_100.jpg','frame_0_1000.jpg','frame_0_1001.jpg','frame_0_1002.jpg','frame_0_1003.jpg']

set1.sort() #will sort the elements present inside the list

If you print the set1 again, you will get it as:
['frame_0_0.jpg', 'frame_0_1.jpg', 'frame_0_1000.jpg', 'frame_0_1001.jpg', 'frame_0_1002.jpg', 'frame_0_1003.jpg', 'frame_1_100.jpg', 'frame_2_10.jpg']